# Why does searching for SSAS which has it's own set of tags, return lots of 'SSA' results first?

Tags: support, search

Compare the results of this search [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SSAS:](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SSAS)

[image]

With this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssas

[image]

Would it not make sense for the search prioritise results that have tags **and** a non trivial number of results?

Comment: The search is parsing 'SSAS' as 'SSA-s' -- that is, the plural of 'SSA'.  This is usually the right thing to do with actual English words but isn't helpful with acronyms, and apparently the search doesn't consult a dictionary to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom is spot on; note also that a quoted search for `"ssas"` doesn't have this treat-as-plural problem.

Comment: Ahhh that's quit interesting.  Using these abbreviations everyday makes you forget the common everyday conventions.

Comment: Enclose your search term by double quotes to achieve an exact search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22SSAS%22