# My team is always listed as last when I search for it

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, old-teams

When I search for my Team ("ics") it is always listed as last elment in the result and the result contains other teams that do not match the filter criteria.

The other teams would match the criteria `ic` but not `ics`.

I have also tested all 3 possible sort options (members, name, created) and the result is always the same.

[image]

Comment: @Kendra yes, i have tested all 3 sorts

Comment: _Maybe_ the search aliases _"ics"_ with _"ic"_, as _"ICs"_ is the plural form of _"[IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit)"_

Comment: @Cerbrus that Sounds reasonable

Comment: Quite possibly related: [Why does searching for SSAS which has it's own set of tags, return lots of 'SSA' results first?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272429/why-does-searching-for-ssas-which-has-its-own-set-of-tags-return-lots-of-ssa)

Comment: This is a problem resulting from overly aggressive stemming. Team names are not natural language, and often are formal titles (which stemming isn't useful for). I'm talking with Team pages project team about using exact search matching per token/word, which should solve this issue. We'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now boost exact matches by team name.  This should be a bit better than it was.